# dynamically change public path in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, base-url, ipfs

i want put my vue js project in ipfs . and because of that i have to change my baseuri or public path to be :

```
/ipfs/[hash string which i get after file added to ipfs]
```

but i cant do that

means i want to set public path be dynamically depends on real url
somethink like this :

```
 module.exports = {
publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?
    '/ipfs/[hash string which i get after file added to ipfs]/' : '/'
}
```

whats your idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Setting empty string isn’t working?

Comment: not working @PetrOdut

Comment: i had the same problem. I solved it by setting publicpath to `./`, but i also use [director](https://github.com/flatiron/director#client-side-routing) for routing with hashes.